# move everything after the 6th backslash up one line with a linux script

Tags: linux

```
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/xyz/fred-episode-110
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/abc/simon-episode-266
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/qwe/mum-episode-39
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/zxc/dad-episode-41
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/asd/bob-episode-57
```

i have many url's saved in a txt file like show above
i want to move everything after the 6th backslash up one line with a script

the txt after the 6th backslash is the title and always different
i need to select the title so i can play it

so i need it to look like this

```
fred-episode-110
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/xyz/fred-episode-110
simon-episode-266
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/abc/simon-episode-266
mum-episode-39
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/qwe/mum-episode-39
dad-episode-41
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/zxc/dad-episode-41
bob-episode-57
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/asd/bob-episode-57
```

i have 
sed
awk
wget

can this be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command:

```
awk -F/ '{print $7; print $0}'
```

E.g.:

```
awk -F/ '{print $7; print $0}' < file.txt > new-file.txt
```

Comment: peter can you please have a look at my post below thank you

Comment: You should never never add questions as answers. But add `sed -e 's/-/ /g'` and also try `info coreutils`.

Comment: how to combine both these commands together ?
sed -e 's/-/ /g'
awk -F/ '{print $7; print $0}' < file.txt > new-file.txt
so that it removes the hyphens just from the title
i used it like this
sed -e 's/-/ /g' < file.txt | awk -F/ '{print $7; print $0}' > new-file.txt
and it removed the hyphens from the title and the url
i need to keep the hyphens in the url

Comment: Ok, it might be easier to use perl =) Try this: `perl -pe '($s=(split /\//) [6]) =~ s/-/ /g and $_=$s.$_' < file.txt`

Comment: thanks i can't run perl on the hardware i can only use sed or awk  if you find a way please let me know thank you

Comment: Ok, this should work: `awk -F/ '{ s=$7; gsub("-", " ", s); print s; print }'`

Comment: that gave me the same title twice top one still has hyphens the one under that was correct no hyphens also gave me a space to the next line

fred-episode-110
fred episode 110
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/xyz/fred-episode-110

simon-episode-266
simon episode 266
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/abc/simon-episode-266

Comment: yes that worked forget comment above i made a mistake thank you for your time

Comment: You welcome :) Will you have nothing to do, read this: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-0

Answer (score -1):

just to add to this

```
awk -F/ '{print $7; print $0}' < file.txt > new-file.txt
```

is there anyway to remove all the hyphens from just the title and leave a space
some of the titles have lots of hyphens 
and it makes it a bit hard to read with the hyphens there

change these

```
simon-episode-2-playing-football-in-the-park
fred-episode-110-the-big-clash-tonight
bob-episode-57
```

to

```
simon episode 2 playing football in the park
fred episode 110 the big clash tonight
bob episode 57
```

thanks for your expertise and time